# Modeling XML for documentation

Tags: xml, documentation

I have several XML files used in my application,

I need to document these XML data files, for example as *Relational Database modeled by ER diagrams*. How to model XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your audience. Who is going to use these models, and what are they going to do with them? Models are there to communicate ideas, so you need to know what ideas you want to communicate and to whom.

It also depends on the data. For some XML document designs, ER diagrams would be hopelessly unwieldy and therefore a waste of effort.

Comment: its for a technical document !